# 500 internal server error when using RetrieveSalesforceObjects when Contact is abscent in CRM?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs

I am having an issue working with *RetrieveSalesforceObjects* Method, I am having 500 interval error whenever I am having a wrong contact id, I tried to follow the recommended method, check

```
%%[

Set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","OptInEmail__c,OptInMail__c,OptInOthers__c,OptInPhone__c,OptInSurvey__c,OptInPersonalEmail__c,SubscriptionLocale__c,ContactablePhone__c,ContactableMail__c,ContactableMessaging__c,SourceSystem__c,ContactableEmail__c,LastNLunSubscriptionDate__c,SMSPhoneAuto__c",
  "Id", "=", "007nLVNxQAOJHDFJH")
  
  if rowcount(@subscriberRows) == 0 then
    ]%%
    <span>What ?</span>
    %%[
  endif

]%%
```

I was expecting my text to displayed, but got 500 error

The I tried to use SSJS to maybe get an error expection :

```
<script runat="server">
   Platform.Load("Core", "1");
   try {
</script>

     %%[

Set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","OptInEmail__c,OptInMail__c,OptInOthers__c,OptInPhone__c,OptInSurvey__c,OptInPersonalEmail__c,SubscriptionLocale__c,ContactablePhone__c,ContactableMail__c,ContactableMessaging__c,SourceSystem__c,ContactableEmail__c,LastNLunSubscriptionDate__c,SMSPhoneAuto__c",
  "Id", "=", "")

]%%

<script runat="server">
    } catch(e) { Variable.SetValue("@error","error") }
</script>

<span>%%=v(@error)=%%</span>
```

But still getting the error 500, ..

Note : this code works perfectly when the id of contact exists in CRM

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: I performed a quick test using ur code... initially I too recieved 500 error.... but was able to fix maketing these 2 changes..... 1) Added additional 'A' to make it 18digit ID [007nLVNxQAOJHDFJHA] .... 2) Make sure you have all those fields are valid..... coz I had to remove all fields and pulled only 'Id and Email' and it worked! ...

Comment: adding full code which worked for me... ````%%[

Set @subscriberRows = RetrieveSalesforceObjects("Contact","Id,Email",
  "Id", "=", "007nLVNxQAOJHDFJHA")
  
  if rowcount(@subscriberRows) == 0 then
    ]%%
    <span>What ?</span>
    %%[
  endif

]%%````

Comment: Why would I make it 18 characters ? I am trying to catch errors in case anyone made a mistake? so it may be 17 characters, 16, I have to take those in considerations, ..

Comment: SF record IDs, specifically in their Case sensitive format (`CASESAFEID`) that marketing cloud uses, are always 18 digit in length; If you have a user enter those IDs, then that's "interesting" (bad) because those aren't exactly user-friendly inputs, and are easy to tamper with - meaning someone typing them in for a retrieve can simply get data about someone else by changing e.g. the last letter of the ID to the previous letter in the alphabet. in other words - you have a potentially much larger problem in your solution design than the one presented here.

Comment: Thanks Jonas for sharing your thoughts... more details by *Markus*  https://markus.codes/2021/02/03/salesforce-id-15-18-digit-lengths